# External html page not loading inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load an externalpage inside `div.On` clicking one div I expect the another web page to be loaded inside another div.But the web page is not loading on the second div.Here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/user1989/xpp5t6nv/9/

```
<div id="fileTreeDemo_1" class="demo" onclick="alert1()">abc</div> <div id="upload_target" name="upload_target" ></div>

<style>
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;

}
div{
    box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
body > div:first-child{
    width:20%;
    border:solid 2px green;
}
body > div:nth-child(2){
    width:80%;
    border:solid 2px blue;
    float:right;
}

function alert1(){

document.getElementById("upload_target").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="https://www.google.co.in" ></object>';

}
alert1()
```

Comment: Try using `iframe` instead of `object`

Comment: i don't think you can load webpage in object like this. you should use iframe

Comment: try to iframe. put your code like this: `<iframe src="link_to_your_html"> </iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```js
function load_home() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="type/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar"> <a href="#" onclick="load_home()"> HOME </a> 
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (unless your page is inside the  google.co.in domain).
Long story here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Your code will work as is using a Url within your own domain.
Most sites do not allow it. Browsers vary in how tolerant they are of it.
If the target is in your control you can add the following to the header of the target page to allow it -

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See this for more.
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

If not you can proxy the external page serverside with php, node.js or asp, then hit your proxied page for the object's data. But that is a whole different topic.